# How to merge multiple data frames rows into a list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple data frames. I need to merge them all and then set one by one column from all df.
I make it simple for you.i have multiple lists .like

```
l1=[a,b,c]
l2=[d,e,f]
l3=[g,h,i]
```

I want my list such that give below.

```
list=[a,d,g,b,e,h,c,f,i]
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining numpy multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959201/combining-numpy-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Comment: For lists - like in your example - the following will work: `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(l1, l2, l3)))`

Comment: Clarified title.

Answer (score 0):

```
l1=['a','b','c']
l2=['d','e','f']
l3=['g','h','i']

list1 = []

for i in range(len(l1)):
  list1.append(l1[i])
  list1.append(l2[i])
  list1.append(l3[i])

print (list1)
```

Comment: Careful! That won't work! After your snippet, the resulting list will be `[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i]`. OP wanted the transpose of the matrix in their question.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `numpy` array

```
np.array([l1,l2,l3]).ravel('F')
Out[537]: array(['a', 'd', 'g', 'b', 'e', 'h', 'c', 'f', 'i'], dtype='<U1')
```

since you mention `pandas`

```
pd.DataFrame([l1,l2,l3]).melt().value.tolist()
Out[543]: ['a', 'd', 'g', 'b', 'e', 'h', 'c', 'f', 'i']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(l1, l2, l3)))
```

worked for me.